# If $\Lambda$ is continuous at one point in $X$, then $\Lambda$ is bounded on $X$.

Tags: real-analysis

This is taken from "Real and Complex Analysis" by Walter Rudin:

> **Theorem 5.4** For a linear transformation $\Lambda$ of a normed linear space $X$ into a normed linear space $Y$, each of the following three conditions implies the other two:
>
> (a) $\Lambda$ is bounded
>
> (b) $\Lambda$ is continuous
>
> (c) $\Lambda$ is continuous at one point of $X$.
>
> **Proof:** Since $\|\Lambda(x_1-x_2)\| \le \|\Lambda\| \|x_1-x_2\|$, it is clear that (a) implies (b), and (b) implies (c) trivially. Suppose $\Lambda$ is continuous at $x_0$. To each $\epsilon > 0$, one can then find $\delta > 0$ so that $\|x-x_0\|<\delta$ implies $\|\Lambda x - \Lambda x_0\|<\epsilon$. In other words, $\|x\|<\delta$ implies $$\|\Lambda(x_0+x)-\Lambda x_0\|<\epsilon.$$ But then the linearity of $\Lambda$ shows that $\|\Lambda x\|<\epsilon$. Hence $\|\Lambda\| \le \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$, and (c) implies (a).

My question concerns only (c) implies (a). The supremum norm is $$\|\Lambda\|=\sup_{x \not=0} \frac{\|\Lambda x\|}{\|x\|}.$$

However, I am not sure how $\|\Lambda x\|<\epsilon$ and $\|x\|<\delta$ (which implies $\frac 1{\|x\|} > \frac 1{\delta}$) imply $\frac{\|\Lambda x\|}{\|x\|} \le \epsilon$, since the opposing inequalities are confusing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $0 < r < 1$. For $x$ with $\lVert x\rVert = r\delta$, you know $\lVert \Lambda x\rVert < \epsilon$. Hence

$$\frac{\lVert\Lambda x\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert} < \frac{\varepsilon}{r\delta}$$

for these $x$. For an arbitrary $y \neq 0$, write

$$y = \frac{\lVert y\rVert}{r\delta}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{r\delta}{\lVert y\rVert}y}_x,$$

where $\lVert x\rVert = r\delta$. Then by the homogeneity of the norm and $\Lambda$, you have

$$\frac{\lVert \Lambda y\rVert}{\lVert y\rVert} = \frac{\lVert \Lambda x\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert} < \frac{\epsilon}{r\delta}.$$

Let $r \to 1$ to obtain the inequality

$$\lVert\Lambda\rVert \leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\lVert \Lambda y\rVert}{\lVert y\rVert} = \frac{\lVert \Lambda x\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}$, How?